# exponential equation for a student in 10th grade

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the equations:

1. $2^{x}+4^{x}+9^{x}=3^{x}+2 \cdot 6^{x}$
2. $1+2^{x}+8^{x}+16^{x}+27^{x}=3^{x}+9^{x}+18^{x}+24^{x}$

I find a solution for each:

1. $x=0$ is a solution
2. $x=1$ is a solution

I don't know if I have other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first equation can be rearranged as:
$$2^{x}+4^{x}+9^{x}=3^{x}+2 \cdot 6^{x}$$
$$ \implies 4^{x}-2 \cdot 6^{x}+9^{x}=3^{x}-2^{x}$$
$$ \implies (3^{x}-2^{x})^2=3^{x}-2^{x}$$
$$ \implies (3^{x}-2^{x})(3^{x}-2^{x}-1)=0$$
This gives 2 solutions 
$$3^{x}=2^{x} \implies x=0$$
$$3^{x}-2^{x}=1 \implies x=1$$

And then again,

$$1+2^{x}+8^{x}+16^{x}+27^{x}=3^{x}+9^{x}+18^{x}+24^{x}$$
Say $2^x=a$ and $3^x=b$.
Then you have
$$1+a+a^3+a^4+b^3=b+b^2+ab^2+a^3b$$
$$(1+a)(1+a^3)=b^2(1+a)+b(1+a^3)-b^3$$
Now $b$ divides RHS and so $b$ must divide LHS.

Hence either $b|(a+1)$ or $b|(a^2-a+1)$.

Now $b|(a+1)$ holds only for $x=1$ and $b|(a^2-a+1)$ holds only for $x=1$.

The exhaustivity proof can be found using simple congruency rules. I am trying. See if you can do something.

Comment: I could not for the 2$nd$. Could u?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Well I didnt check. Now that you say so, I am going to check.

Comment: Neither do I...

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

For $1.$  let $2^x=a,3^x=b$

$$\implies a+a^2+b^2=b+2ab\iff(a-b)^2+(a-b)=0$$